# Mathematically equivalent expressions produce notably different results

Tags: plotting, numerics, trigonometry

I came across a curious result when plotting the solution to a differential equation.

When I use the following command

```
Plot[1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 (t)] - 1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 (t)], {t, 0, 8 Pi}]
```

my output looks as follows

[image: first output]

but when I instead shift the first `Sin` function by `2 Pi` like this

```
Plot[1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 (t) - 2 Pi] - 1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 (t)], {t, 0, 8 Pi}]
```

I instead get an output that looks as follows

[image: second output]

Note also that the more the first `Sin` function is shifted, the worse the output becomes:

[image: thirst output]

Furthermore, if the second `Sin` function is shifted by the same amount as the first, then the output is the same as the original output when none were shifted:

[image: fourth output]

Of course, shifting the `Sin` function by `2 Pi` should make no mathematical difference. What then is the underlying reason for the difference in output?

I understand that the magnitude of the differences is small (order of 10^-15 it seems) and if you set the `PlotRange` in any of the shifted examples to be the same as in the first non-shifted command, then the difference will not be perceivable. However, the reason behind those numerical differences is still of interest to me. Furthermore, the logic that the `Plot` command follows to set the plot range in a way that captures those small-magnitude features of the shifted result is curious in itself.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `Evaluate`, i.e.,  `Plot[Evaluate[
  1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 (t) - 2 Pi] - 
   1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 (t)]], {t, 0, 8 Pi}]`

Answer (score 3):

You must adjust your working precision.

```
Plot[1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 t + 8 Pi] - 1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 t], 
{t, 0, 8 Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 5]
```

[image]

However, using the machine precision would give you the following:

```
Plot[1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 t + 8 Pi] - 1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 t], 
{t, 0, 8 Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

[image]

But why? Compare the scale of the plots. Also, if you use a `WorkingPrecision` of `0.8`, the picks are not represented and Mathematica tries to plot things on the order of $10^{-15}$ and you get the plots you have. Notice the discontinuities you get in the plot below.

```
Plot[1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - Pi] Sin[2 t + 8 Pi] - 1/2 HeavisideTheta[t - 2 Pi] Sin[2 t], 
{t, 0, 8 Pi}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 0.8]
```